# How to removing trailing .0 from a series column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping

I am trying to remove the trailing `.0` from the rows of `CAS/ID NO` column using this code:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = ' https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/sda/sdNavigation.cfm?sd=edisrev&displayAll=true'
html = requests.get(url).content
df_list2 = pd.read_html(html)
df2 = df_list2[0]
df3=df2.dropna(subset = ['CAS/ID NO'])
df3['CAS'] = df3['CAS/ID NO'].to_string()
df3['CAS'] = df3['CAS/ID NO'].astype(str).replace('\.0', '', regex=False)
df3
```

It is steadfastly resisting all of my efforts.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to convert in to type `.astype('int64')`:

```
df2['CAS'] = df2['CAS/ID NO'].astype('int64')
```

##### Example

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = ' https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/sda/sdNavigation.cfm?sd=edisrev&displayAll=true'
html = requests.get(url).content
df_list2 = pd.read_html(html)
df2 = df_list2[0]
df2 = df2.dropna(subset = ['CAS/ID NO']).copy()
df2['CAS'] = df2['CAS/ID NO'].astype('int64')

df2
```